# elasticsearch, document disappear in search after update of size less than 17

Tags: elasticsearch

**SOLVED**
Upgraded elasticsearch to 0.90.3

Good day, I have a problem with elasticsearch.

1. I have a page with list of items (ordered by itemName)
2. Goes to edit item and update item's Name

   ```
   ejs.Document(index, type, item_id).source($scope.master).doUpdate(); 
   (elastic.js - It's doesn't matter I guess, it's works )
   ```

   It's updated successfully - I have update document with version 2, and updated fields.
3. Go back to list of items, my query

   ```
   {
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "sort": [
    "itemName"
    ],
    "version": true
   }
   ```

And updated item - disappeared in list

My list:

```
1. Old name a
2. Old name b
3. Old name c
N. ...
```

I change "Old name b" to "Old name b 2"

And I get if "size": 10 :

```
1. Old name a
2. Old name c
3. next item ...
N. ...
```

But if I set "size": 20 or more - appeared.

```
1. Old name a
2. Old name b 2
3. Old name c
4. nex item ...
N. ...
```

**So why updated items disappeared in list if size < 20 ?**

Elasticsearch version: 0.90.0

**SOLVED**
Upgraded elasticsearch to 0.90.3

Comment: you are changing the name of the item, and in the query you sort by item name. maybe the new name is no longer within the top 20 ?

Comment: I change item like: old name -> old name2. So it should be on the same place and if "size": 20 - it's ok. Updated Question

Comment: **SOLVED**
Upgraded elasticsearch to 0.90.3

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have a reference to the bugfix/change that addressed this? Cheers!